# visibleWhen with if else condition in eclipse menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to configure the visibility of a popup menu based upon the resource selected and the view within which the resource is selected.The condition to be matched is the project the resource belongs to must be a java project

What I need is:

1)If I select a resource from the editor, then the condition must be tested(say whether the project the resource belongs to is a java project)
2)else If I select any resource from the Navigator View, the same condition must be tested 
3)else If I select any package fragments from the Package-Explorer view then the condition must be tested.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **test** element and the org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature property tester to test if a given IResource belongs to a java project.  Check out some of the other platform provide [PropertyTesters](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions) for more options.